# AD DC for the domain could not be contacted

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I know there are some question about "An Active Directory Domain Controller for the domain could not be contacted"

[An Active Directory Domain Controller for This Domain Could Not be Contacted](https://serverfault.com/questions/91258/an-active-directory-domain-controller-for-this-domain-could-not-be-contacted)

[An Active Directory domain controller for this domain could not be contacted](https://serverfault.com/questions/55060/an-active-directory-domain-controller-for-this-domain-could-not-be-contacted)

,but somehow its not helping me.

Im running a Win 2008 R2 and on this system there are some virtual machines. Installed R2 on VMware server and I was able to put the machine into my domain. After that VirtualBox got installed (newest version) and R2 got installed on it also but Im not able to put the machine into the same domain.

```
The domain name "mydom" might be a NetBIOS domain name.  If this is the case, verify that the domain name is properly registered with WINS.

If you are certain that the name is not a NetBIOS domain name, then the following information can help you troubleshoot your DNS configuration.

DNS was successfully queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate a domain controller for domain "mydom":

The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.mydom

The following domain controllers were identified by the query:
ccwmlab40.mydom


However no domain controllers could be contacted.

Common causes of this error include:

- Host (A) or (AAAA) records that map the names of the domain controllers to their IP addresses are missing or contain incorrect addresses.

- Domain controllers registered in DNS are not connected to the network or are not running.
```

I dont get it. Everything is the same as on the other VMWare machine and somehow there are no domain issues. Could be this a VirtualBox issue or did I something wrong on my R2? Its funny, because im able to ping everything and everybody who is in the domain but I get the message that there is no domain like mydom? There is something wrong. Any ideas? Thank you

Edit: If you need any other information, please tell me what else I could post here.

ipconfig /all on the VirtualBox System:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : TestR2
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : mydom

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : mydom
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-00-27-6C-62-F9
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c091:55b6:72e7:3ac4%11(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.15(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Donnerstag, 21. Juni 2012 12:17:34
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Freitag, 22. Juni 2012 12:17:33
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.2
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.2
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 235405351
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-73-40-21-08-00-27-6C-62-F9
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.22.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.mydom:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : mydom
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

DHCP Server is `192.168.22.1`
ccwmlab40.mydom is `192.168.22.6`

Comment: Are you using the same DNS on this server? I am not clear what we're talking about (whether this is a VM or physical server). Can you ping ccwmlab40.mydom?

Comment: Im a touch confused as to the setup here.  Are you running Windows server 2008 R2 as a physical box with a copy of vmware server and virtual box running on that?  Do you then have guest OSes running under these?  Or are you running a full blown ESX server for some machines and you are trying to get a VM running in virtual box on your physical workstation to connect to the ESX VMs?

Comment: 2008 R2 as physical box with vmware and vbox on it :) (and on vmware + vbox are win 2008 R2 running too)

Comment: Yes Im able to ping ccwmlab40.mydom from my vbox (and everywhere else too: vmware, physical)

Comment: Thanks for this.  What are the ip addresses of the DC (and DNS) and the guest vm you are trying to connect to the domain?  Would also check firewall config on both the DC and the computer you are connecting, been bitten many times by that lol.

Comment: Hi. I edited my post and there are now all the IPs. As I know firewall is disabled everywhere, its not helping.

Comment: Um, so you're running a 2008 R2 server with VMWare Server (which is End-of-Life) and VirtualBox (which is a desktop virtualization package), in your production environment and you're wondering why you're having problems?

Comment: The "end of life" VMWare is working well. Im wondering what you are trying to tell me. Is there the problem with VBox? Not made for Win 2008?

Comment: I'm telling you that if you're running two competing type 2 hypervisors (one of which is EOL) on top of a 2008 R2 server that is also holding other roles, you're gonna have a bad time. Use type 1 (bare metal) hypervisors in production and don't use desktop software like VirtualBox on servers. You should also do something about the fact that you're using a single label domain name for your AD. That's also bad.

Comment: And because of that I get "-" for my question right? Its always so nice to ask you people here stuff...

Comment: If I ask questions outside of server fault about domains, servers and so on people are telling me that I should use server fault. If Im here to ask stuff about server, domains people are telling me Im not welcome. Somehow its not easy...but thank you.

Comment: @ree I do feel for you, and you're right in that it's hard to know where to stand sometimes. However, the key selling point of Server Fault to its users and contributors is that it's geared solely around professional IT. Things are generally very different in the world of commercial and corporate IT and you have several things in your setup which most people would consider "Insane". Now, this is fine for playing around with, but sometimes "You're doing it wrong." can be the right answer.

And trust me, everyone here has heard it from someone at least once ;)

Comment: @ree `"If I ask questions outside of server fault about domains, servers and so on people are telling me that I should use server fault."` - Those people would be wrong. Not everything is on-topic just because it deals with servers or AD domains. If you're not acting in a professional capacity, then SuperUser might be a better fit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are doing is a "single label domain", and is not recommended by Microsoft. 
Have a look here for some suggestions on how to solve this problem:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300684/en-us

Reviewers: Too much information to post here, so I just post the link.

Comment: Yeah, there's just so much about this setup that is wrong that I missed the fact that this is a single label AD domain at first glace. +1

Answer (score 0):

This error happened to me when I had 2 NIC's on separate networks with one DNS configured for local network, and the other one DNS for internet. After disabling the internet one (in NICs configuration) the domain started to work again. Then I turned internet DNS on again, and everything is working fine.